# How to add blank space in oracle pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, crystal-reports-2008

```
 SELECT lpad(nvl(substr(to_char(nvl(edt.leave,'''')),1,10),'''') || nvl(decode(leave_time,null,'''',
 decode(edt.leave_time,''P'',''-PM'',''-AM'')),''''),10,'' '') LeaveType,
 CASE WHEN substr(to_char(rh.holiday_date,''dd/MM/yyyy''),1,10) IS NOT NULL THEN
      substr(to_char(rh.holiday_date,''dd/MM/yyyy''),1,10)
      ELSE
      ''          ''
      END HolidayDate, FROM TABLE
```

I have that part of code in my package, that is accessed by crystal reports... whenever I export the Data it doesnt give me the 10 spaces on my ELSE(enclosed by single quotes) when the record doesn't have a holiday_Date Where did I go wrong?

Comment: That does generate spaces, so something else (Crystal, presumably) is stripping them. Is it keeping the left-padding on LeaveType? Couple of notes though; firstly you might want to look at the [alternative quoting mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) so you don't have to manually escape the single quotes, making it more readable and easier to run standalone. Secondly an empty string is the same as null in Oracle, so or example `nvl(edt.leave,'')` doesn't achieve anything. You could simplify this quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Use rpad() function

```
rpad(' ',9)
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rpad.php

Comment: CASE WHEN substr(to_char(rh.holiday_date,''dd/MM/yyyy''),1,10) IS NOT NULL THEN
      substr(to_char(rh.holiday_date,''dd/MM/yyyy''),1,10)
      ELSE
      rpad(' ',9)
      END HolidayDate - like this?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant

Comment: THan its probably a christal report issue or feature and I cant help more

Comment: try `rpad('-',9,'-')` to see if it enters your ELSE

Comment: You can thus conclude that your issue is in crystal reports and not SQL. I can't help you further

Answer (score 0):

Don't manipulate everything in query if you are using crystal reports instead try below:

Change query like this... instead of case statement on date take date column in the query and manipulate in crystal reports.

```
 SELECT lpad(nvl(substr(to_char(nvl(edt.leave,'''')),1,10),'''') || nvl(decode(leave_time,null,'''',
 decode(edt.leave_time,''P'',''-PM'',''-AM'')),''''),10,'' '') LeaveType,
 rh.holiday_date FROM TABLE
```

Now in crystal reports take a formula `@Date` and write below code:

```
if IsNull(Cdate(rh.holiday_date))
then "          " //Adding 10 spaces
else Cdate(rh.holiday_date)
```

Now run and export the report